# What is the semantic meaning of 'this.object.position' in Three.JS's trackball?

Tags: javascript, dom, graphics, user-controls, three.js

I've spent some time trying to figure out what this.object.position is supposed to represent in this Trackball control: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js

The author not only saves the original value of position (for reset purposes) but also keeps track of the lastPosition whenever the position changes (or not) after each frame.

```
... // the first half of the constructor

var lastPosition = new THREE.Vector3();

... // more initialization


// for reset
this.position0 = this.object.position.clone();
```

At first I believed that it stood for the position of the camera, but there's also a 'this.eye' variable, so that would be a conflict. Then I thought that it had something to do with the position of the drawing surface on the DOM, but since it's a size 3 vector that theory doesn't hold much weight either.

I know this may be a stupid question, but I will really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.object.position` is the camera position. (see note)

`this.eye` is the vector from `this.target` to `this.object.position`. The target is the point  the camera rotates around.

```
_eye.subVectors( _this.object.position, _this.target );
```

Note: This is assuming that the camera is *not* a child of another translated or rotated object -- in which case, the control will not work correctly.

three.js r.58